# Can't add scripts in bundle (asp.net mvc 4)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I tried to add a few scripts at the same bundle

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/scripts").Include("~/Scripts/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.jcarousel.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.jcarousel-control.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.jcarousel-autoscroll.min.js"));
```

but as result I got on my page only one, the first script

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js"></script>
```

(Of course, I added all scripts in `Scripts` folder.)
What's wrong? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chain the `Include` calls:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/scripts")
    .Include("~/Scripts/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js")
    .Include("~/Scripts/jquery.jcarousel.min.js")
    .Include("~/Scripts/jquery.jcarousel-control.min.js")
    .Include("~/Scripts/jquery.jcarousel-autoscroll.min.js"))
```

Comment: but why othes script bundles work without `Include`, for example, `bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                            "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));` and the same about css `bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/reset.css",
                "~/Content/style.css",
                "~/Content/nivo-slider.css",
                "~/Content/ie8-style.css"));` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/Yourscripts").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.jcarousel.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.jcarousel-control.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.jcarousel-autoscroll.min.js"));
```

And It works.